# Can we limit the traffic used by user in dante server?

Tags: proxy, socks, dante

Can we limit the traffic used by user in dante server?

I have a dante socks5 server I want to limit the traffic used by a user to 2GB only

If I can do this with dante please help else if I can't any other open source socks5 server or soloution?

Comment: what is the goal you are trying to Fix, it looks for me a X and Y Problem, however i can only find to limit the Bandwith but not traffic per user, as reference take a look to https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/latest/config/bandwidth.html - this is even not known to me if squid could do that

Comment: Additonal Info; It seems that Dante server, if the Man-Page is correct, has oly the Ability to rate-Limite the Bandwith but not the traffic, (https://linux.die.net/man/5/sockd.conf)